# Stop messages to my new iPhone from appearing on my old iPhone

Tags: iphone, messages

I got a new iPhone, and I gave my old one to my husband. Naturally, I want to disable my Apple account and iMessage on the old phone. How do I do this without affecting my own account?  Each time I receive a message on my new phone, he is receiving the same message on his phone.  We have two different phone numbers.

My husband does not have his own iTunes account and prefers not to have a separate account. The phone is unlocked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to disassociate your Apple ID from iMessage on his iPhone. You can do this by following the steps outlined below. Don't worry, iMessage/FaceTime account settings are separate to iTunes account settings (so you can choose to have different Apple IDs for each)

1. Open the Settings app
2. Scroll down to and tap 'Messages'
3. Scroll down to and tap 'Send & Receive'
4. Tap 'Apple ID' (which should list your Apple ID)
5. Tap 'Sign Out'

This will disassociate your Apple ID from iMessage on that iPhone and still leave it intact on your new one. Your husband will still be able to send and receive iMessages using his number. You will probably want to do the same for FaceTime too otherwise he will receive FaceTime calls for you and vice versa!

Comment: I will absolutely do this for you if I could figure out how to "up-vote" and "accept" the answer.  I have looked all over but not sure how to vote.

Comment: @RosanaHalprine Next to the answer there are two arrows (up and down) and a tick. Clicking the arrow up and down votes answers respectively and the tick accepts the answer. Oh, and welcome to Ask Different! :)

Comment: Ah yes, okay, I see it.  So I clicked the check and then tried to check the up arrow.  Got a message "needs a 15 reputation."  Hope that helps and thank you again for your help.  This site, and your answer particlarly, has been a great help to me.  May be checking in with you from time to time when I have an issue that I cannot solve.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to ask why your husband does not want a separate account but if it's just for keeping billing iTunes purchases under your then that can be done now with Apple's family settings. Making an Apple ID is free and he can use his existing email. Remember he can access a lot of your personal info even if you disable the iMessaging. I know married people should have nothing to hide but you still need some privacy (like incase you want to surprise him on his birthday). He will have access to your calendar and noted without passwords and if he knows your password then there will be access to all.
 Regardless of all that, reset your old phone to wipe all content out and then set him up with his own ID on that phone. From there you can add him to your "Family" on your iCloud account and you can be set as the primary and even your payment method (for iTunes and other purchases) can be used for the whole family. You can also share photo and photo albums easier. It's a great feature my wife and I use now. You can also share location for an hour or indefinitely to not have to call or text to see when he or she will get somewhere (yes that maybe more privacy boundaries one might not want to cross but amazingly enough, my wife and I have found it very useful.

Comment: Not a privacy issue.  I gave my husband my old iphone 3gs that has all of my apps, contacts, etc.  My new phone is an iphone 5c.  He does not use texting, FB, and most of the apps.  He only wants to make and receive calls and take photos.  Anyway, he just got tired of seeing all of my contacts and texts.  I have had to drag him kicking and screaming into the modern iphone world.  We shall see what happens.  Thank you so much for your help.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to keep the data on the phone, just go into Settings --> General --> Erase all Content and Settings. This will reset the phone to how it was when you purchased it (it will keep the iOS version it had when you reset it, however).

Comment: that doesn't work, I came here because I'm facing this issue after previous owner done full restore to factory defaults